# Calculating zenith and elevation angles for satellite as seen from the ground

Tags: python, astropy, pyephem, satellite, pyproj

I have the latitude, longitude, and height for a satellite and for a ground observer.  I am trying to calculate the satellite zenith angle and satellite azimuth angle, for the satellite, as seen from the ground.

I'm currently trying to solve this using `astropy`.  The documentation [describes](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/generated/examples/coordinates/plot_obs-planning.html) how to calculate the zenith and azimuth angle for the Sun.

I tried to place the satellite straight above the observer, so that the zenith angle should be 0° (or the elevation angle 90°).

```
In [41]: ground = astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation(lat=3*u.deg, lon=5*u.deg)

In [42]: sat = astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation.from_geodetic(3*u.deg, 5*u.deg, 700*u.km)
```

However, clearly `.transform_to(AltAz(...))` does not mean what I think it means, for the answer is not what I want:

```
In [43]: print(sat.get_itrs().transform_to(AltAz(location=ground)))
<AltAz Coordinate (obstime=None, location=(6345216.684243768, 555134.5274868822, 331574.3153428908) m, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt, distance) in (deg, deg, m)
    (314.96287134, 63.2970069, 773970.24385554)>
```

I expected the elevation angle to be close 90°, not 63°.

There's also some routines in [pyorbital](http://pyorbital.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyorbital.astronomy.get_alt_az) but it doesn't seem to contain what I'm looking for.

I believe it should also be possible using [`pyephem`](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem), except that this seems to expect I get satellite information from a catalogue.  I already have the lat, lon, altitude.

I've also looked at [`pyproj`](http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/) but I think this is only for objects at the geoid.

How can I calculate the altitude and azimuth for the satellite as observed from the ground?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26256/33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this from `pyorbital`.  The relevant function is [`get_observer_look`](http://pyorbital.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyorbital.orbital.get_observer_look).  For some reason, it wants the time, and it apparently requires all inputs are ndarray objects.  It warns when the azimuth is ill-defined (such as when the zenith angle is zero).  But it does work:

```
In [50]: import pyorbital.orbital

In [51]: print(pyorbital.orbital.get_observer_look(atleast_1d(1), atleast_1d(1), atleast_1d(700), datetime.datetime.now(), atleast_1d(1), atleast_1d(1), atleast_1d(1)))
(array([261.11934085]), array([89.99999915]))

In [53]: print(pyorbital.orbital.get_observer_look(atleast_1d(10), atleast_1d(0), atleast_1d(700), datetime.datetime.now(), atleast_1d(0), atleast_1d(0), atleast_1d(0.1)))
/home/zmaw/u237009/.conda/envs/FCDR37a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyorbital/orbital.py:112: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  az_ = np.arctan(-top_e / top_s)
(array([270.]), array([25.73173269]))

In [54]: print(pyorbital.orbital.get_observer_look(atleast_1d(10), atleast_1d(0), atleast_1d(700), datetime.datetime.now(), atleast_1d(0.1), atleast_1d(0.1), atleast_1d(0.1)))
(array([90.56944651]), array([26.03504444]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning up your inputs a bit:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import AltAz, EarthLocation

ground = EarthLocation.from_geodetic(lat=3*u.deg, lon=5*u.deg, height=0*u.km)
sat    = EarthLocation.from_geodetic(lat=3*u.deg, lon=5*u.deg, height=700*u.km)

result = sat.get_itrs().transform_to(AltAz(location=ground))
print(result)
```

Which produces the expected 90 degrees:

```
<AltAz Coordinate (obstime=None, location=(6345.21668424, 555.13452749, 331.57431534) km, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt, distance) in (deg, deg, km)
    (89.99999672, 89.99991123, 700.)>
```